# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) =\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

I need to decide if the following function uniformly converges:

$$f_n(x) =\sqrt[n]{1+x^n} \quad, \quad x\in[0,\infty)$$
I found the sequence pointwise converges to

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 \; ,  & \text{$x\in[0,1]$} \\
x \; ,& \text{$x \in(1,\infty)$}
\end{cases}$$

I tried to find the supremum of $\;|f_n-f|\;$ but got nothing. Any ideas how I can get forward?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** For $x>1$,
$$ \sqrt[n]{1+x^n} - x = \frac{1}{x^{\frac{n-1}{n}}+x^{\frac{n-2}{n}}(1+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}+\cdots +x^{\frac{1}{n}}{(1+x^n)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}} \le \frac{1}{n}$$
and for $x\le 1$,
$$ \sqrt[n]{1+x^n} - 1 = \frac{x^n}{1+(1+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}+\cdots +{(1+x^n)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}} \le \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Impressive... is there something more simple than that? how did you think of this solution?

Comment: On second thought, I don't think I understand what formula did you use here.

Comment: @user401516 The formula $$u^n - v^n = (u-v)(u^{n-1}+u^{n-1}v+u^{n-2} v^2 +\cdots +v^{n-1})$$ is used.